# This query runs fine, but as an update statement in Oracle it fails

Tags: oracle, sql-update, left-join

```
SELECT  arinvt.buyer_code_id
FROM arinvt
LEFT JOIN arinvt_vendors
ON arinvt.ID = arinvt_vendors.ARINVT_ID
where arinvt_vendors.vendor_id like 61690 
and arinvt_vendors.is_default ='Y' 
and arinvt.buyer_code_id is null

update arinvt 
set arinvt.buyer_code_id = 66 
SELECT arinvt.buyer_code_id 
FROM arinvt 
LEFT JOIN arinvt_vendors 
ON arinvt.id = arinvt_vendors.arinvt_id 
(where arinvt_vendors.vendor_id like 61690 
and arinvt_vendors.is_default ='Y' 
and arinvt.buyer_code_id is null)
```

> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>   *Cause:
>
> ### < *Action:

I looked at the other (duplicate) question before I posted mine and tried this Update:

UPDATE 
    ( SELECT arinvt.buyer_code_id
             FROM arinvt
        LEFT JOIN arinvt_vendors ON arinvt.id = arinvt_vendors.arinvt_id
      where arinvt_vendors.vendor_id like 61690 and arinvt_vendors.is_default ='Y'
      and arinvt.buyer_code_id is null
     )x
SET arinvt.buyer_code_id = 66

and I get:

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ARINVT"."BUYER_CODE_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help please, we need this to fix our production system.

Comment: Fails how? Error? Wrong data updated?

Comment: Please dont add code or other useful information in the comments. EDIT your question and provide it there. Also, only code doesnt help much. Clarify what you want to do

Comment: Oracle does not support ANSI 92 joins in UPDATE or DELETE statements. I agree it would be neat if they did. The answers in the linked thread will give you solutions which will work in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here:

```
arinvt_vendors.is_default 'Y'
```

I'm guessing you probably meant

```
arinvt_vendors.is_default = 'Y'
```

Comment: Can you post the UPDATE query that fails with ORA-00933?

Comment: update arinvt
set arinvt.buyer_code_id = 66
(SELECT arinvt.buyer_code_id
FROM arinvt
LEFT JOIN arinvt_vendors ON arinvt.id = arinvt_vendors.arinvt_id
where arinvt_vendors.vendor_id like 61690 and arinvt_vendors.is_default ='Y' and arinvt.buyer_code_id is null)

Comment: Assuming the 66 is a typo the syntax looks OK.  I noticed that it seems like you want to select the non-null buyer_code_id to do the update though from the inner query (e.g. SELECT arinvt_vendors.buyer_code_if FROM ...)